# Scale the columns of an RcppArmadillo matrix using lambda function

Tags: r, lambda, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I want to min-max the columns of a matrix using `RcppArmadillo` and a lambda function, without using a for loop. I have tried this in the code below but this just returns the original matrix. How to replace the original values with the scaled values?

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat min_maxC(arma::mat X) {
   arma::mat Xsc(size(X));
   Xsc = X.each_col( [] (arma::vec& x) { return(x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)); });
   return Xsc;
}

/***R
X = matrix(sample(100,50), 5,10)
min_maxC(X)
*/
```

Comment: `X.each_col( [] (arma::vec& x) { x = (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)); });`